# Running a cmd from Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to migrate some code from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to Azure SQL. The code uses `xp_cmdshell` to run a `.bat` file along with some parameters that moves files around and uploads said files to a git repository.

Now I have to migrate it to an Azure SQL PaaS server, where I can no longer use `xp_cmdshell` - is there some workaround to this problem? Is there a way to run that `.bat` file with parameters?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Now I have to migrate it to an Azure sql **PaaS** server, where I can no
> longer use xp_cmdshell, is there some workaround to this problem? is
> there a way to run that .bat file with parameters?

Indeed, there is no way to get access to xp_cmdshell in PaaS offerings.

As the alternatives:

- [Automate workflows for a SQL database by using Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure)
- Possibly, Azure SQL Managed Insance + Python integration:

  ```sql
  EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python' , @script = N'your code'
  ```