# File Handling in stored procedure - Azure SQL Serverless Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-storage-account

I'm looking for solution to store a file in **Azure Storage Account - File Share** from a Stored Procedure. I'm not using this file content in my tables, it's all photo references. Could you please suggest me if any of these approaches would help or any other alternatives?

1. Calling Azure Serverless Functions from the Stored Procedure
2. Accessing the Physical Path from Stored Procedure, like using “CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE” command.
3. Calling xp_cmd to store the files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried them? and which way do you prefer?

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043133/running-a-cmd-from-azure-sql/65043728#65043728

Comment: @LeonYue none of the above worked. Had to go with private sql server installation.

Comment: @Pandiarajan According my experience, Azure SQL database doesn't support access local files, and only support Blob storage. If you want achieve that, you may need think about Azure SQL managed instance, it has almost the same feature with local SQL Server.

Comment: Hi @Pandiarajan, hope you're doing well. May I post it as the answer?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL database doesn't support access local files, and only support Blob storage. That's why those approaches don't work.

Just for now, we can not find any supports for the file storage. You may could add a new [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) that Azure SQL database product team could see it.